# Context API isn't returning the id of clicked element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm building a React app in which a user choses how many tickets they want and then selects their seats from a layout.

I'm using the context API which is working for various elements but I'm trying to return the **id** of seats the user chooses.

This is the component with the clickable elements I need to get the IDs from -

```
class ChooseSeats extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(<Context.Consumer>
            {(context) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>Remaining tickets: {context.state.remainingSeats}</p>
                        <p>Chosen seat: {context.state.chosenSeat}</p>

                        <div>
                        <div id="A1" onClick={context.chooseSeats}>
                            <img src={freeSeat} alt="freeSeat"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="A2" onClick={context.chooseSeats}>
                            <img src={freeSeat} alt="freeSeat"/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="A3" onClick={context.chooseSeats}>
                            <img src={freeSeat} alt="freeSeat"/>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                
                )}
            }
        </Context.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is the context file -

```
export class Provider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        chosenSeat: " ",
        remainingSeats: 8
    }

    render() {
        const { remainingSeats, chosenSeat } = this.state
        
        return(
            <Context.Provider value={{
                state: this.state,
                chooseSeats: (event) => {
                    this.setState({
                        chosenSeat: event.target.id,
                        remainingSeats: remainingSeats - 1
                    })
                    console.log(chosenSeat)
                },
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

In my actual app, the `remainingSeats` value is originally taken from some dropdown menus in which the user choses their tickets but for simplicity's sake I've just given it a default value of 8 in this case.

The `choseSeats` function is running because the `remainingSeats` value reduces by 1 each time a seat is clicked but it doesn't return the id of `chosenSeat`. I've tried `chosenSeat` as a string and an array and neither returns anything.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked what the `event.target` is? Is it the `img` or the `div`? Also, those `div`s with `onClick`s should be `button`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `event.target.id` is an empty `string`.  Although you attached the `onClick` on the `div` (which should be a `button` to make it accessible), if you click on the child `img`, the `event.target` is the `img`.

You can use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) - it refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached (`div`) - or you can create inline functions instead and pass the ids.

So, instead of

```
<div id="A3" onClick={context.chooseSeats}><img ...
```

you can use

```
<button onClick={() => context.chooseSeats('A3')}><img ...
```

And update your `chooseSeats`, which receives an ID now, not the `event`:

```
chooseSeats: (id) => {
  this.setState({
    chosenSeat: id,
    remainingSeats: remainingSeats - 1,
  })
  console.log(chosenSeat)
},
```